# Git: how to disable command suggestion

Tags: git, version-control, terminal

Sometimes, when I make a typo in a Git command, Git will offer suggestions for the command it thinks I was trying to type. For example:

```
$ git statu
git: 'statu' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Did you mean one of these?
        status
        stage
        stash
```

I find this functionality to be very slow; sometimes, I will have to wait a few seconds before the Git process exits. Is there any way to turn off this command suggestion functionality? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way of doing that. But, if you are annoyed by slow response, don't make errors. :) Kidding aside, you can alias some common commands, e.g., `alias gits="git status"`, `alias gitc="git commit -am"`, etc. so that your chance of typing typos becomes less.

Comment: One way to avoid typos is to install git completion in your shell. I normally type `git stat` then press tab. The completion script will even auto-complete branch names. Google `git-completion`

Answer (score 1):

Try the [`git config help.autoCorrect`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-helpautoCorrect) setting:

```
 git config help.autoCorrect  -1
 or
 git config help.autoCorrect  0
```

That is in decisecond, but if the value of this option is negative, the corrected command will be executed immediately.
If the value is 0 - the command will be just shown but not executed. This is the default.